# Calculate $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^b \frac{r}{a-r\cos \vartheta}dr\,d\vartheta$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^b \frac{r}{a-r\cos \vartheta}dr\,d\vartheta$$

When I put this in `Mathematica` just give me a long formula, but I know that
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\!\!\!\!\int_0^b \frac{r\,drd\vartheta}{a-r\cos \vartheta}
=
2\pi(a-\sqrt{a^2-b^2}).
$$

Comment: You need to tell Mathematica that you assume $a>b$.

Comment: ```f[x_, y_] := x/(a - x Cos[y])
Integrate[f[x, y], {x, 0, b}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, Assumptions -> a > b]```

Comment: Are we sure this integral actually converges?  To me it seems to blow up quite badly.